# Why didn't the Arashiyama team just deactivate and reactivate their triggers during ep 15?

Tags: world-trigger

During the battle, there is a moment when the Arashiyama team stops to rethink their strategy in an alley. Both Jun and Ai are severely impaired (Jun carrying gravity bullets, and Ai with a severed leg).

We know that when they deactivate their triggers, the Trion bodies vanish, and when the trigger is activated, it is rebuilt wholly.

So why didn't they just pop in and out of their triggers to remove those impairments?

We know for a fact that repeated trigger activations in the same day have an impact upon the users Trion reserves:

Osamu couldn't summon even a blade when he changed a second time in the same day, during episode 4. But it is stressed everywhere that Osamu's Trion potential is crappy, and they are Rank-A agents.

Answer (score 1):

The possibility of a trap, and the training they received.

Think about it, when is the best time to attack?

When the enemy can't defend.

They had no idea if they were being watched, and since it takes only a split second for someone with chameleon to hold a trion blade to their throat, it would make no sense to risk turning human.